# Make each feature box the same height - HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a layout where I want to display a service section with an ICON, Title and little description for each box.

I am trying to keep the same design pattern and make the box all the same height when they are in the same row.

Right now if one title is bigger than the other and resize the screen, the box wont have the same height.

Help would be appreciated, been trying for days.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n23jvecf/51/)

```css
.services {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #a1a1a1;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.format {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
}

.service {
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100%/3);
  margin: 0 -2px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="services">
    <div class="format">
      <div class="service">
        <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
        <h2>Service Name - Testing long title - Long long long Long long long </h2>
        <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service">
        <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
        <h2>Service Name</h2>
        <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service">
        <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
        <h2>Service Name</h2>
        <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service">
        <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
        <h2>Service Name</h2>
        <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service">
        <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
        <h2>Service Name</h2>
        <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service">
        <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
        <h2>Service Name - Testing long title - Long long long Long long long </h2>
        <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service">
        <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
        <h2>Service Name</h2>
        <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="service">
        <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
        <h2>Service Name - Testing long title - Long long long Long long long </h2>
        <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: grid ? https://jsfiddle.net/e43p1sfa/ or flex ? https://jsfiddle.net/e43p1sfa/1/

Comment: That would be good if the last row was centered, so when I resize the screen and I have less than 3 boxes in the row, I want them to be centered. How to do that ?

Comment: flex then, and justify-content:center. https://jsfiddle.net/kr89pay5/  See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ to start learning about flex .

Answer (score 0):

You may want to apply `display: flex` to `.format`, not `.services`.

```css
.services{
  display: inline-block;
    background: #a1a1a1;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.format{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.service{
  background-color: grey;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100%/3);
    margin: 0 -2px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="services">
    <div class="format">
        <div class="service">
            <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
            <h2>Service Name - Testing long title - Long long long Long long long         </h2>
            <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
            <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
            <h2>Service Name</h2>
            <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
            <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
            <h2>Service Name</h2>
            <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
            <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
            <h2>Service Name</h2>
            <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
            <div class="service">
            <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
            <h2>Service Name</h2>
            <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
            <div class="service">
            <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
            <h2>Service Name - Testing long title - Long long long Long long long         </h2>
            <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
            <div class="service">
            <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
            <h2>Service Name</h2>
            <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
            <div class="service">
            <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
            <h2>Service Name - Testing long title - Long long long Long long long         </h2>
            <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.services{
  background: #a1a1a1;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.format{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
}

.service{
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0 -2px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="services">
      <div class="format">
        <div class="service">
          <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
          <h2>
            Service Name - Testing long title - Long long long Long long long
          </h2>
          <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
          <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
          <h2>Service Name</h2>
          <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
          <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
          <h2>Service Name</h2>
          <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
          <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
          <h2>Service Name</h2>
          <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
          <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
          <h2>Service Name</h2>
          <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
          <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
          <h2>
            Service Name - Testing long title - Long long long Long long long
          </h2>
          <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
          <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
          <h2>Service Name</h2>
          <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="service">
          <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
          <h2>
            Service Name - Testing long title - Long long long Long long long
          </h2>
          <p>Lorem IPsum dummy text test test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not what I am looking for as it puts everything in the same column. I want to keep the same design pattern, 3 in a row, and if 1 or 2 it would center them rather than be aligned to the left.